# System Media Player Progress as UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display a UISlider that acts as a progress bar. I want the progress of the UISlider to be the current progress of the song being played in the system media player.

This is my code:

In my headers.h file:

```
static MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
NSTimer * currentTimeUpdateTimer;

UISlider *timeSlider;
```

In loadView:

```
    musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];

    timeSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((((scrollView.contentSize.width/2)+(scrollView.contentSize.width/12))-10), 100, (((scrollView.contentSize.width/2)-(scrollView.contentSize.width/6))+20), 80)];
    timeSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    timeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    timeSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    timeSlider.alpha = 0.8;
    timeSlider.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:timeSlider];
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
currentTimeUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentiPodItemTime) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];

userIsScrubbing = NO;
```

These are the functions for controlling and setting the value of the UISlider

```
- (void)updateCurrentiPodItemTime {
MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];

if (nowPlayingItem == nil) {

} else {
double currentTime = musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;

if (!userIsScrubbing)
    timeSlider.value = (float) currentTime;
}
}

- (void)handleScrubberTouchDown:(id)sender {
 userIsScrubbing = YES;
}

- (void)handleScrubberTouchUp:(id)sender {
userIsScrubbing = NO;
}

- (void)handleScrub:(id)sender {
musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = timeSlider.value;
}
```

But what happens is the UISlider value is always full and does not progress as the song progresses.

The point of the UISlider is to also allow the user to scrub through the now playing music.

Comment: Cleaned the tags. Now add the tag for the **one** language you **actually** use (hint: none of those you tagged). If you don't know, you better don't wrote code.

Comment: @Olaf Ok sorry. But I think you need to have a look at your grammar. "You better don't write code" make sense not.

Comment: "make sense not" :D Anyway, For me your implementation is ok, I don't see why it's not working. Have you tried to layoutSubview?

Comment: This is a programming language site. As long as it is clear what I mean and I have no problems with the grammar of my programs, such flaws are not subject to discussion here. Feel free to try German. (Btw. your citation is wrong. I wrote "wrote", which obviously is wrong.

Comment: @RomOne I put the timer implementation in layoutSubviews I still got the same result.

Comment: @Olaf you literally just changed "write" to "wrote" in your edit you just did. I don't want to start a flame war here and fun fact I actually speak German.

Comment: Anyway you both wrong. First you shouldn't have done such comment at the first place. This give a bad image of that website which main purpose is to help each others. If someone do something wrong, explain to him instead of using bad sarcasm. Your comment was constructive but not respectful of others.

Comment: @TheHellOTrofasdasd Sorry I don't see, I'm using the exact same logic as you in my player, and it's working fine :/

Comment: @RomOne are you using your own player or the system music player which I am trying to use.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm using my own... Btw are you sure your method "handlScrub" is called?

Comment: @TheHellOTrofasdasd: I did not edit the original comment (how should I, as it was already 5 mins old).

Comment: @RomOne Yes I add it as the action of the UISlider. Am I geting the currentPlayingTime wrongly? Because updateCurrentiPodItemTime is called each second and should change progress depending on the now playing.

Comment: @Olaf the pencil icon means it was edited.

Comment: Ohh yeas good idea, check your timerSlider.value, see if it's greater than 1

Comment: @TheHellOTrofasdasd: Yes, but not that one. But yes, I now belive you **do** speak German! TO get back to the subject: apparently you still have not found out which language you are programming in. Otherwise, how about adding the correct tag?

Comment: @Olaf This is getting us nowhere. iOS is Objective C and C.

Comment: The code is **not** C! Objective-C is not C. But as you refuse to edit your question, this really is useless.

Comment: @RomOne It seems the value of the slider is always 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out. The max value of the uislider was 1. So I set the max value to be the total length of the song in seconds.

Comment: Well done, that's what I thought when I told you to check if the value was greater than 1 ;)

Comment: @RomOne Yes. I should have done that before. But alas I didn't. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RomOne I just noticed that for some reason in another function I call [[%c(SBMediaController)sharedInstance] play]; and when it is called with this new uislider my device freezes. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell if it's coming from a memory leak or something? (just have a quick look to the memory usage, if it's not too high) If it is just freezing without any error, just press pause, to see where your app is stuck (maybe a loop?)

Comment: @RomOne I isolated the freeze to this line here:  timeSlider.value = (float) currentTime;

Comment: If I comment out that line I don't get the crash.